# Linear Algebra Orthogonality Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Prove the statement below is true or give a counter example to show it is false.

Let {$v_1,v_2$} be an orthogonal set of nonzero vectors and let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be any nonzero scalars. Then {$c_1v_1, c_2v_2$} is also an orthogonal set.

I'm pretty sure this is true, I'm just not sure how to solve it...

Comment: The inner product (i.e. dot product) is bilinear, and "orthogonal" means that the inner product equals 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two vectors are orthogonal if and only if their inner product is $0.$ Now the inner product is bilinear, which means $\langle c_1v_1,c_2v_2 \rangle=c_1c_2\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0$ as $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0.$ Therefore $c_1v_1$ and $c_2v_2$ are orthogonal.

Comment: If the inner product defined on a complex linear space then it must be $\;\langle c_1v_1,c_2v_2\rangle =c_1\overline{c_2}\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\;$ . In this case it is the same result, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal if and only if $v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0$.